# Exporting two module under same directory not working when requiring from same file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have two js file under same directory:
`main/file1.js` and `main/file2.js`.  Then I call it under my test folder `test/files.js`

If I have this in my file1.js:

```
function file1(){
    let result = "a";
    return result;
}
module.exports = file1
```

Then my file2.js:

```
let v = "c" //this is the error that make file2 undefined.  scope issue.
function file2(){
    let result = "b";
    return v;
}
module.exports = file2
```

Then in my test file I am requiring both files.  file1's `steps` function works fine but the file2's `steps2` is undefined.  Any thought?

```
const assert = require('assert'); 
const steps = require('../main/steps');
const steps2 = require('../main/steps2');

describe('steps', function(){
    it('make steps', function(){
        assert.equal(file1(), 'a');
    });
    it('make steps2', function(){
        assert.equal(file2(), 'b');
    });
})
```

Comment: what happens if you reverse the order?

Comment: Your files are named `file1.js` and `file2.js`, but you're requiring `steps.js` and `steps2.js`. Is that just a typo in the example, or the actual code?

Comment: @Cully not a typo, I am requiring  `const steps2 = require('../main/steps2');` because `step2` is being exported in file2.

Comment: @Bravo, reverse the requiring order in the test files?

Comment: @MingHuang You don't require the function name, you require the file name. It should be `const steps = require('../main/file1'); const steps2 = require('../main/file2');`

Comment: wow @Cully good pickup - how does steps function work!!

Comment: my bad, i was trying to rename the function and file names and I got little confused.  let me change it, thanks @Cully.  But still not working lol

Comment: @MingHuang I just re-created your files and they work fine. Could you paste the output of `ls main` ?

Comment: You're also calling functions named `file1()` and `file2()` in your test file. Copy/paste your original files, without editing. I imagine it will be clear what the issue is then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're requiring the function name when you should be requiring the file name. Your requires should look something like this:

```
const steps = require('../main/file1');
const steps2 = require('../main/file2');
```

Comment: @Bravo My guess is that there's coincidentally a file named `../main/steps.js`

Comment: this works fine.  you are right the import should be the file name and it turns out there are some issue with my file2's code(scope issue).  I will add that error on there to reflect the error.